# How should I choose which column should be indexed to decrease searching in data?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I have a table like below, and there are about **3 million** rows of data, I need search in this table by **date** and **ticker**, but I'm confused about indexed these columns or not. I test a different combination of indexing them, but I can't find a better state.

2 question :

- how can I know which column should I index?
- what is the effect of indexing on insert and update queries?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `_b_price` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tickerDate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ticker` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numOfTrades` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vwap` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tickerDate` (`tickerDate`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `ticker` (`ticker`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2667983 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: @Strawberry :)) ok bro, I will change my dates, I'm a newbie and it's my first question, I changed it and show create table

Comment: I don't know what the tickerdate column is for. An index (or possibly a UNIQUE index) on (date,ticker) (or perhaps (ticker,date)) would seem desirable - instead of those individual indexes

Answer (score 0):

One can only guess at indexes by looking at a schema.  One needs to see the queries to judge what indexes to have.  "Search by date and ticker" is too ambiguous.

But, since I have dealt with tables like this, I can give you some tips:

- Volume for indexes can exceed the size of INT.
- Prices are not integral.
- Shouldn't tickerDate be a `DATE` datatype??
- Toss `id` unless you have a particular use.  Promote the `UNIQUE` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Wait!  You are allowing only one row per day, you have millions?  Maybe `tickerDate is a misnomer??
- The `PRIMARY KEY` should probably be `(ticker, date)`.  That eliminates the need for `KEY(ticker)`.
- You *may* also need `INDEX(date)`.  -- I need to see your queries.
- I suspect that any traded item has an *ascii* 'ticker', so don't use `CHARSET=utf8`.
- Normalize tickers, replace with (probably) a `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (16M limit).

More:

- I think you meant for `UNIQUE(TickerDate)` to be `UNIQUE (Ticker, TickerDate)`.  (And then promote to PK, as mentioned above.)

Comment: thx, your tips are so useful for me, I will check one by one, every day I have more than four thousand record, the ticker is a unique code of stocks.

Comment: I added a little more.